# Can you group specific thread id's into unique task groups in OpenMP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Before running my program, I do this:

```
export KMP_AFFINITY=explicit,proclist=[0-47],granularity=fine
```

I then spawn 48 threads:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(48) 
{
  int id = omp_get_thread_num();
}
```

Each thread in the parallel construct now has an ID that matches the processor ID.

Now...

Processor 0 and processor 24 are actually on the same core. Processors 24 to 47 are hyperthreaded with 0 to 23.

I have a vector of worker objects that the threads are using. They pick an object from the vector based on their id.

I'm trying to get the 0/24, 1/25, 2/26, etc... hyperthreaded cores to pair up on a specific "worker" object, and then use a task group within the object:

```
class Worker {
public:
  int wId;
  Worker(int i) {
    wId = i;
  }
  void doWork() {
    // Can I make a task group for the 2 threads reaching this code together?
    // will barriers, taskgroups, critical pragmas wait for all 48 threads?
  }
};

int main() {
  vector<Worker> workers;
  for (int i = 0; i < 48; ++i) {
     Worker w(i);
     workers.push_back(w);
  }
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(48) 
  {
    int id = omp_get_thread_num();
    workers[id % 24].doWork();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if something like this would work. My assumption is that any use of `taskgroup` or `barrier` or `critical` pragmas within that `doWork()` function would affect all 48 threads, and not just the 2 threads that should be sharing the object.

Is this true? How can I create a group of threads of known processor binding (i.e. put thread 0 and thread 23 into a group) to do what I want?

Comment: Did you consider nested parallelism, with first level of 24 threads (attached to the cores) and second level of 2 threads (which will use the 2 hyper-threads of the same core)?

Comment: @Gilles -- yes, that's something I'm trying to test out now, but I don't know how to pin the 0/24, 1/25, etc pairs to the same core in that kind of a scheme. I know it will require a change to the `KMP_AFFINITY` and the `num_threads`  arguments but I'm not sure what exactly to set these to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone interested... as @Gilles pointed out, the solution is nesting. The trick is getting the exports right:

```
export OMP_NESTED=1
export OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS=2
export KMP_HOT_TEAMS=1
export KMP_HOT_TEAMS_MAX_LEVEL=2
export OMP_PROC_BIND=spread,spread
export OMP_PLACES=cores
```

And then you can just do this:

```
#pragma omp num_thread(24) {
  #pragma omp num_thread(2) {
    // paired hyperthread code
  }
}
```

(source: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/process-and-thread-affinity-for-intel-xeon-phi-processors-x200)